Color a specific country in a map
I'm trying to color a specific country (France) on this map and I don't know how to do it. Please help me! Thank you!
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

world <- ne_countries(scale = 50, returnclass = 'sf')
ggplot(world) + geom_sf(aes(fill = continent), color = 'black')+ coord_sf(crs = st_crs(3035),
           xlim = c(2800000, 6200000), 
           ylim = c(1500000, 4000000)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c('grey', NA, 'grey','grey', NA, NA, NA, NA), guide = 'none', na.value = 'white') + theme(panel.background = element_rect(),panel.grid.major = element_line(linewidth = 0.1))


See here for several possible answers.

Set the fill manually to France:
ggplot(world) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = name))+ 
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(3035), xlim = c(2800000, 6200000), ylim = c(1500000, 4000000)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("France" = "red"), na.value = "grey")



thanks very much !!!
Please  tell me how I can add a point on the map with the following coordinates : 47°26'28.96"N    and    3°41'32.01"E . Thanks for help!

You can color-code countries (a) by adding them as separate layers, or (b) by creating an indicator variable. See also this answer.
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Load world data
world <- ne_countries(scale = 50, returnclass = 'sf')

(a)
# Filter data for France
france <- world[world$name == "France", ]

# Plot the map with two layers
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = world, aes(fill = continent), color = 'black') + 
  geom_sf(data = france, fill = 'blue', color = 'black') + 
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(3035), xlim = c(2800000, 6200000), ylim = c(1500000, 4000000)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(), panel.grid.major = element_line(linewidth = 0.1))

(b)
# Create a new column to specify the color for France
world$color <- ifelse(world$name == "France", "France", "Other")

# Plot the map
ggplot(world) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = color), color = 'black') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("France" = "blue", "Other" = "grey")) + 
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(3035), xlim = c(2800000, 6200000), ylim = c(1500000, 4000000)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(), panel.grid.major = element_line(linewidth = 0.1))


thanks!!!! Please tell me how I can add a point on the map with the following coordinates : 47°26'28.96"N and 3°41'32.01"E . Thanks for help!
